# How to crop excess alpha background?

Tags: image, alpha, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to crop out the excess height of my image

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this, perhaps using `Image`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of "Godot already does that"…

Given an `Image` get a rectangle with the "used" (not fully transparent) pixels:

```
var rect := image.get_used_rect()
```

And now get a new image from the one you have, cut by that rectangle:

```
var new_image := image.get_rect(rect)
```

And there you go.

---

If you only want to crop at the end, you can use `crop` instead which does not create a new image:

```
image.crop(rect.end.x, rect.end.y)
```

Or if it is only vertically, we can do that too:

```
image.crop(image.get_size().x, rect.end.y)
```